# What is the proper rendering for zero radius rounded <rect>?

Tags: svg, language-lawyer

How should this SVG document be drawn? It is a rounded rectangle with the X radius explicitly set to zero and the Y radius non-zero:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 288 216" height="3in" width="4in">
  <g>
    <rect
       rx="0"
       ry="36"
       y="36"
       x="54"
       height="108"
       width="162" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zsgmowv/) on your browser.

Every program I have tried (Inkscape, Chrome, Safari, IE 11) renders it like this:

[image]

This sets `rx` equal to the value of `ry`. Is this correct? The [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/shapes.html#RectElement) says:

> 4. Otherwise, if a properly specified value is provided for ‘ry’, but not for ‘rx’, then set both rx and ry to the value of ‘ry’.

But I don't see how that applies here because `rx` *is* properly specified. The spec only restricts negative values:

> For rounded rectangles, the x- and y-axis radii of the ellipse used to round off the corners of the rectangle. A negative value for either attribute is an error (see Error processing).

If `rx` is taken as 0 (instead of set to `ry`) this defines a 1D degenerate ellipse which would give the rect unrounded (i.e. square) corners:

[image]

My reading would make this the correct behavior according to the spec, but I find it difficult to believe that every application implements it incorrectly.

Note that I am not saying the observed behavior wouldn't be convenient, nor do I require any workaround. I only want to know does it conform to the spec and if so, what specific language in the spec defines it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the suggestion. Firefox renders with square corners, unlike Inkscape and the other browsers. Okay, so I've got Firefox in my corner...

Comment: Excellent, raise bugs on the bugtrackers of the rest then.

Comment: Also, it appears that on Safari, if you set the rx and ry as styles they are not applied unless a ry or rx attribute is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<rect>` should be rendered without rounded corners per the SVG specification. Firefox implements that part of the SVG specification as written.

Comment: Alrighty, [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576811) and [Inkscape](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1533302) bugs submitted.